# How to create multiple links from a single array of strings Rails - Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I know it might seem simple but I've tried to create multiple links from this array in Rails

```
array = ["/uploads/content/attachment/folder/file1.pdf/file2.pdf/file3.pdf"]
```

What I want to do is create a link for `file1` and another for `file2` and so on.

I've tried to use the join and separate method, image_tag, content_tag and many many different cycles in Rails but every single one ends up like the link above.

Comment: You must include in your question the code that is causing these errors and what you have done to try to fix it. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this if I understood correctly:

```
array = ["/uploads/content/attachment/folder/file1.pdf/file2.pdf/file3.pdf"]
base = "https://www.example.com/" #the first part of the link, that's same for all links

links = array.first[1..-1].split("/").map{|a| base + a}
puts links
#=>  "https://www.example.com/uploads",
#    "https://www.example.com/content",
#    "https://www.example.com/attachment",
#    "https://www.example.com/folder",
#    "https://www.example.com/file1.pdf",
#    "https://www.example.com/file2.pdf",
#    "https://www.example.com/file3.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear.

I assume the array will be like this:

```
array = [
  "/uploads/content/attachment/folder/file1.pdf/file2.pdf/file3.pdf",
  "/uploads/content/attachment/folder/file12.pdf/file23.pdf/fildf34.pdf",
  "/foo/boo/folder/file1.doc/file2.docx/file11.pdf"
]
```

It splits links for `folder/`

```
links = array.map{ |a| a.split('folder/') }.flat_map do |path, files|
  files.split('/').map{ |file| path + "folder/" + file }
end

p links
#=> [
      "/uploads/content/attachment/folder/file1.pdf",
      "/uploads/content/attachment/folder/file2.pdf",
      "/uploads/content/attachment/folder/file3.pdf",
      "/uploads/content/attachment/folder/file12.pdf",
      "/uploads/content/attachment/folder/file23.pdf",
      "/uploads/content/attachment/folder/fildf34.pdf",
      "/foo/boo/folder/file1.doc",
      "/foo/boo/folder/file2.docx",
      "/foo/boo/folder/file11.pdf"
    ]
```